# how to use the debug library to interact with a required lua file's upvalues

Tags: lua, closures, upvalue

If I have a Lua function `f` I can look at all the upvalues in `f`'s closure by using the `debug.getupvalue` function. Similarly if I have a file `foo.lua` I can look at the upvalues by first doing `foo = loadfile(foo)` then using `debug.getupvalue` in the same way that you would for `f`. If I `require` `foo.lua` is there anyway I can figure out what the upvalues for the closure of `foo.lua` are?

Comment: You can also assign a value to upvalue by `debug.setupvalue` and join two upvalues by `debug.upvaluejoin`

Comment: very true, in fact in my specific case I'm trying to use debug.`upvaluejoin`

Comment: @Julian: What is your question? Your question text doesn't seem to state the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module loaded by `require` is not preserved by `require`'s standard loaders. Only the return value from the execution of that module is preserved.

So while you can inspect any upvalues for any function exported by the module, you cannot inspect upvalues that are only accessed by non-accessible functions.